# JSF, datatable and onRowClick

Tags: java, jsf

I want a commandlink to be executed when the row is clicked in my datatable. I've created a `<h:commandLink>` in one of my columns, where a parameter is passed through `<f:setActionPropertyListener/>` Is there a clean solution to fire this link by a rowClick? Sure I could workaround my missing knowledge with some jQuery but there should be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, using richfaces:

1. Define a `<a4j:jsFunction>`, with `<a4j:actionparam>` - the id of the row
2. `onRowClick="functionName(#{item})`"

Comment: Well solved it by setting up a JS function and `onRowClick="function(#{obj.id})"`- thought there would be a common way to deal with this. Anyways thanks Bozho